# Spacer in the vertical menu [undefined]

Tags: javascript, menu, webix

I am trying to set some space between the menu items, but default Webix spacer represents as an undefined value. 
It seems a bit confusing, so I'll be glad to get an advice.
http://webix.com/snippet/ab5a1e3d

```
view:"menu",
layout:"y",
width:200,
data:[          
  { id: "1",        icon: "user",       value:"Profile"},
  { id: "2",        icon: "envelope-o", value:"Inbox"},
  { id: "3",        icon: "book",       value:"Articles"},          
  { },
  { id: "4",        icon:"support",     value:"Support"},
]
```

Comment: So, Amarillo, does my answer help?

Comment: @Cerbrus oh yes, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because it's trying to read a `value` on the spacer, which is `undefined`.

Use this, instead of `{}`:

```
{ value: '' },
```

[Updated example](http://webix.com/snippet/f60c4114).